# Deploying an aurelia.cli built app

Tags: aurelia

I have built a simple aurelia web page without a back end, and I am now interested in going into production. I used Aurelia-cli for bundling, hoping this would be simple, but I am not sure how to proceed. Which files should I upload to the server to have the site working? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you downvote, at least provide a reason, it's only common courtesy.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is exactly the same issue I am researching because, as usual, the Aurelia team -- although wonderous -- continues to leave unanswered the most basic questions. <Sigh>

Answer (score 9):

In a nutshell:

- `au build --env prod`
- copy the `index.html` to your main deployment folder on your server
- copy the `/scripts` folder to the same location.

Comment: How does this work with static resources such as images? Is it better to create a gulp task that copies everything you need to a release folder and then use that?

Answer (score 0):

we created a deployment script that:

- runs the build
- creates a build-directory with the current timestamp.
- copies all assets into that directory (so that we can verify that we have all pieces together)
- and then pushes the whole thing to production

replace the last step with your actual deployment method

```
au build --env prod
buildtarget=../build-$(date +%F-%T)
mkdir $buildtarget
cp -LRvip index.html scripts $buildtarget

ncftpput -R server /prod/path/ $buildtarget/*
```

Comment: I believe you won't want the `i` flag to `cp` since it enables interactive mode. I think the prefect command is `cp -fLprv` (force, follow links, preserve, recursive, verbose).

Comment: you are probably right, i'll double check that and i'll update my answer, thanks