# How to publish an aurelia project in IIS

Tags: iis, aurelia

I am publishing my Aurelia project in Azure from VS Code without problems but I don't know how to publish it in an IIS

regards

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to publish _to_ IIS or _for_ IIS? How are you publishing to Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have execute **au build --watch** and I have copied and pasted the files generated in the wwwroot folder (in my case) inside the folder of my IIS web site and all works fine

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.open command prompt as administrator.

2.enter to the Aurelia project folder.

3.run `au build --env prod` command to build project.

4.this command will generate a dist folder under the project folder.

5.now open iis.

6.right click on the server name and select add website.

7.feel the detail like site name, port number, and the path.

note: select the dist folder as a website path.

[image]

8.after creating site. select site name then click on browse from the cation pane.

[image]

refer this article for more detail:

https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/publish-aurelia-project-with-visual-studio-2017/2944

[Deploying an aurelia.cli built app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934736/deploying-an-aurelia-cli-built-app)

Comment: Thanks after execute au build --env prod I get several errors:error: Error: Path variable [contenthash] not implemented in this context: [contenthash].css

Comment: You need to downgrade webpack package to v4.2.0 . It looks like extract-text-webpack-plugin v4.0.0-beta.0 doesn't support webpack v4.4.1.You can read more about this issue [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/763) github issue

Comment: When I execute au build --watch while I develop the project I get the wwwroot folder with he index.html and the chunks perfectly. I asume that I can point the folder of my site in IIS to this wwwroot folder generated too?

Comment: @kintela in my opinion, you need to use the build folder with iis. did you try to use wwwroot folder?

Comment: @kintela then you could post your solution as an answer and mark it. it will help other people whi face similar issues.

Comment: @kintela sorry, I can not understand what you mean?

Comment: I just wanted to say that I am very busy in my work and I had forgotten to answer that it already worked for me and I have already published my answer